# How @ConfigurationProperties works internally in spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have used Spring `@ConfigurationProperties` to map values from properties file to java object. It works flawlessly and I am trying to find the logic behind that,

1. I tried Java reflection packages to create proxy but it allows only interfaces. For classes I need to use third party library which I would like avoid at this point.
2. I explored the source in IDE as well as in Github but not able to get the
   actual code.

Can anyone direct me in the right way to find the logic behind the @ConfigurationProperties and how it works?

Comment: may be here https://programmersought.com/article/25581101625/

Comment: Thank you @Deadpool, helped a lot